# Is it possible to rerun CucumberJVM test right after fail?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm a beginner in test automation, and I have a question. Is it possible to rerun a test, for example, 2 times right after it fails? I want to have just one report. I tried using a rerun plugin, but I needed to configure it with 2 test runners, and then there were 2 separate sets of results. Another thing I tried was adding 2 in the pom.xml build, but once again, there were only 2 reports via 2 profiles, or if I did it in 1 profile, it would overwrite the old results. So my question is, is there any correct approach to merge these results together or just rerun it right after a failure and then continue?
Stack: Selenium,Java,Cucumber,Maven
Im using basic testRunner:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "stepDefinitions",
        monochrome = true,
        tags ="@cronjob-version",
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "json:target/CucumberTestReports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "html:target/CucumberTestReports/CucumberTestReport.html",
                "junit:target/CucumberTestReports/CucumberTestReport.xml",
                "rerun:target/failedrun.txt"

        }

)
public class testRunner {



}
```

Build:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>testRunners/testRunner.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Short answer: No, it is not possible.

Comment: No option for now. You may try like this, generate json reports and club them after run then convert them into HTML.